# how to setText only once, but it relates to many activities

Tags: java, android

I have code in my `MainActivity`, to set time and date with String variable,

I want to call it from another activity,

```
try {
    try {
        SimpleDateFormat hf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        SimpleDateFormat dsf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
        Date h = hf.parse(sHOURS);
        Date d = df.parse(sDATES);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(h);
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
        String newTime = hf.format(cal.getTime());
        txt_hours.setText(newTime);
        sHOURS = newTime;

        cal.setTime(d);
        String newDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
        txt_dates.setText(newDate);

        String newDays = dsf.format(cal.getTime());
        txt_days.setText(newDays);

    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

} finally {
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
```

**In my all my layout :**

```
<include layout="@layout/sems_head_info" />
```

In this layout txt_times, txt_dates & txt_days

Comment: if you want to setText() of fields in MainActivity then you will do it like this MainActivity.txt_dates.setText("Text"); from other activities.

Comment: Or you can simply pass text with intents and set them in onCreate of MainActivity.

Comment: create a protected method in your baseClass and then call that method in your activity where you want to display it.?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a java class to do your job. Then you call to that java class in any activity.. Otherwise, you can add the code to the activity what you want to display the time

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in **MainActivity**

Like this

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance = this;
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void setDateTime() {
        try {
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat hf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                SimpleDateFormat dsf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
                Date h = hf.parse(sHOURS);
                Date d = df.parse(sDATES);

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(h);
                cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 1);
                String newTime = hf.format(cal.getTime());
                txt_hours.setText(newTime);
                sHOURS = newTime;

                cal.setTime(d);
                String newDate = df.format(cal.getTime());
                txt_dates.setText(newDate);

                String newDays = dsf.format(cal.getTime());
                txt_days.setText(newDays);

            } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } finally {
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
        }
      }
}
```

and call it from another Activity Like this

```
public Class AnotherClass() {
     // call this method
     MainActivity.getInstance().setDateTime();
}
```